# Apply multiple gradient colours in one image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to apply multiple colours in a single photography.

The effect that i want is like this one:

[image: http://houston.startups-list.com/]

I've been playing with standard gradients, big brushes, opacities and saturations, but none of them give me this great colours overlayed to the image.

Does somebody know any tutorial to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like it could be a linear gradient in a bit of an angle, but since you can make a bit more versatile gradients by brushing and this is already somewhat familiar to you, here's how to do that in Photoshop:

1. Make a new layer and brush in the colors

   - Use hard round brush and don't leave any gaps ...or do if that is what you are going for.

[image]

2. `Filter > Blur > Gaussian blur`.

   - Radius: 147%
   - The radius value depends on the look you're going for and the size of your image.

[image]

3. Blending the color to the image

   - Blending mode: Color
   - Opacity: 55%

[image]

Make note that the Blending modes and opacity levels are pretty subjective. For example: For a really light image, you might wanna use Multiply instead and for some images you might wanna try multiple color layers and multiple blending modes...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this in illustrator, you need to create a Gradient Mesh with [Mesh Tool](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-introduction-to-the-mesh-tool-and-creating-a-mesh--vector-22401).

Once you have a Mesh, just change points on the Mesh to desired color to create desired effect. Sorry no Tutorial, just go learn and experiment. There are lots of good tutorials on the 'Mesh Tool' and creating 'Gradient Meshes'.

[image: A Gradient Mesh Layer at 70% over the image]

Comment: Dont know why downvoted. While not the most detailed answer with screenshots, this does answer it. I'll upvote you to negate it.

Comment: I down voted originally because simply answering "use a mesh, go find tutorials" was a very, very poor answer. I've removed my down vote now though. I still don't feel this is a good answer because it does not describe *how* a mesh is to be used. But, your screenshots lean a little in that direction.

Comment: I did leave a VERY help link, to a well organized video, that does goes over the Mesh Tool. Which tells me your really not putting a whole lot of effort into finding a solution. Just waiting for someone to solve your problem...

Comment: Note: I did not pose the question. And "use a mesh" with a link is a poor answer, sorry.

Comment: Lol, sorry for my lack of effort in miss labeling you as the 'asker'.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to @BurningLemons Adobe Illustrator answer would be to use a set of objects with gradients with one of the color stops set to transparent. Once you have your objects you can mix & match opacity and blending modes to achieve your desired effect.

[image: Image with a single gradient overlay, where the gradient has a transparent color.]

[image: Image with multiple gradient overlays, and multiple stacked objects.]

In the above image, note that the individual path (with a gradient fill) has been adjusted. You'd need to change each object separately if you construct your image this way.

Photo from [Flickr Commons](https://www.flickr.com/photos/nationalarchives/4029309050/) & [The National Archives UK](https://www.flickr.com/photos/nationalarchives/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though the image has been desaturated first and gradients liberally applied to a layer above as in:

[image]

This creates something akin to this:

[image]

(Photo credit: Wikipedia)